# How to keep orientation of 3d object regardless of coordinate system change?

Tags: matrix, rotation, transformation

I'm trying to transfer orientation of 3d objects from Unity to my engine. They have different coordinate systems.

In Unity:
Left-Handed X is right, Y is Up, Z is forward and Rotations is CCW in ZXY order

In my engine:
Right-Handed X is right, Y is Down, Z is forward and Rotations is CW in XYZ order by default but can be any (ZYX, XZY and etc).

To do that I save forward and up vectors from Unity to file, and read it back in my engine. Then I calculate glm::lookAtLH matrix from this vectors, extract euler angles from this matrix in XYZ order, then calculate rotation matrix from this angles in any order (xyz order by default).

My problem is that objects orientation changes after that but I dont want this. What is the proper way to do that conversion of rotation angles so my objects keep the same orientation regardless of all that changes in coordinate systems and rotation orders?

Comment: Rotation is not commutative, unless the rotation angles are close to zero. So unless all your rotations are small, Mxyz will never be equal to Mzxy. Also, forgive me, but "Suddenly, rotation ordre changed" gave me a good chuckle. Please give a better description of your problems, and include formulas/code if you want good answers.

Comment: I want to transfer orientation of objects from Unity to my 3d engine, but problem is that in Unity we have zxy rotation order and in my engine it's xyz order.

Comment: That is the way I apply orientation vectors to objects in my engine: calculate glm::lookAtLH matrix, then extract euler angles from this matrix in xyz order then apply this angles in xyz order (yep i make the same matrix twice). Problem Is I dont know how to change order in this operation, and dont know do i really need to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's a lot better! I don't have much time right now, I'll try to answer that as soon as possible.

Comment: By the way, just so I understand correctly, are the coordinate systems the same in both cases? If yes, then you don't need to decompose into three rotations. Just take the final matrix Mxyz and plug it in your engine.

Comment: I tried to extract euler angles from glm::lookAtLH matrix in different order  but it seems to give me correct result only if i extract them in xyz order. Little example: we have rotation xyz(90,0,90) in xyz order, how to know angle values for the same rotation in zxy order?

Comment: Coordinate systems in Unity and my engine are different. In Unity its left handed in my engine its right handed. Even rotation clockwise is different. That is the reason why i save forward, up vectors from Unity instead of direct eueler angles.

Comment: Ah ok, so... 1. I think what you want to do can be achieved with decommositions using "Givens  rotations" (wikipedia has a section on how to do that) 2. Can you edit that into your question, and precisely indicate what the difference between coordinate systems are with formulas or code?